# Изменение url в адресной строке браузера

Tags: url, ajax

Возник вопрос такого плана:

Имеется сайт "site.ru" необходимо по AJAX'у подгрузить страницу с пользователями, которая располагается по адресу "site.ru/users/". Подгрузить то я подгрузила, только встает другой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке браузера тоже изменилось url на "site.ru/users/", просто хочу весь сайт перевести на AJAX, но вот думаю, пользователям не понравится, что они, к примеру не смогут дать своим друзьям ссылку на самих себя ну или иную другую страницу. Вот сайты типа [vk.com](http://vk.com) и [odkl.ru](http://odkl.ru) они же тоже на AJAX'е подгружают контент, иначе бы было невозможно слушать музыку и передвигаться по страницам, и хочу заметить, что URL у них изменяется. Прошу гуру мне помочь.

Comment: А что это за дискриминация, чего удалили мой коммент, что за фигня такая?

Comment: Линк был как раз на ответ, зачем его удалили?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста ещё раз, может тут, какой то автомат? спам защита

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы без перезагрузки **сменить** адрес в браузере можно использовать `History API`, а именно [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/#The_pushState().C2.A0method). Само собой, это будет работать только в браузерах, которые поддерживают `HTML5`.

Простейший пример:

```
var redirect = '/users/';
history.pushState('', '', redirect);
```

За большим идите по [ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/) и знакомьтесь с деталями.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а ещё не подскажете как бороться с такими ужасными браузерами, как IE? просто так ссылки и оставлять <a href="/users/" onclick="ajaxContent('/users/');">Пользователи</a>
или я не права?

Comment: Новые IE с ними работают хорошо, а на старые ориентироваться - себе дороже будет. ИМХО.

Comment: Ну а как же быть с офисными работниками? Которым приходится юзать, то что им установили? Вот сидят на ХР и не могут с IE7 сойти, так как прав нету...

Comment: тут же в дагонку и SEO нужно же линки как то сохранить...

Comment: Если ваш сайт ориентируется и на них, то можете помучиться. В принципе, ваш вариант со ссылками имеет право жить.
Но мне с этой темой тесно работать не приходилось - ни с SEO, ни со старыми браузерами, потому ничего подсказать не могу. Да и это тянет на еще один вопрос. [a](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/), [b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193858/pushstate-and-seo), [c](http://tinyurl.com/99egqxv), [d](http://www.seonews.ru/columns/detail/120290.php)

Comment: Вот либа кроссбраузерная для хистори апи
http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/

Comment: vk.com работает на IE 8 без проблем. Адрес меняется, и я не думаю что здесь скрыта большая тайна. Они делают, значит и мы можем.

Comment: @nMike, а вы бы обратили внимание на то как именно изменяется адрес в IE8. Вот:  
http://vk.com/feed**#**/friends?section=online

Comment: можете подсказать, при перезагрузке страницы выдает 404, что надо сделать, какой код добавить?

Comment: @Taron, такое происходит из-за того, что сервер пытается найти указанный путь; надо настроить сервер так, чтобы он отдавал `index.html` на запрос любого несуществующего ресурса

Comment: но мне надо, что бы ajax-ом загруженная страница осталось с этим же url. htaccess-ом просто можно редиректит на другой url, а там url теряется

Comment: зависит от ваших настроек, связи с ajax'ом не вижу, т.к. там страница вообще не перезагружается; задайте [новый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) вопрос вместо комментирования существующих

Answer (score 2):

Я сейчас изучаю эту же тему и вот этот плагин [jquery Address docs](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/).

Comment: я написала свою собственную функцию, и теперь у меня сайт полностью работает и как на AJAX и так же у тех, у кого выключены java скрипты