# Как добавить GET параметр к URL без перезагрузки по нажатию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть задача добавить GET параметр по нажатию на элемент.

Допустим

```
url = http://xx.x/index
```

По нажатию на

```
<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="1" />
```

`url` стал `url = http://xx.x/index?brand[]=1`

> Важно чтобы все это было без перезагрузки.

Comment: А что вы попробовали? И что у вас не получилось? И каким местом здесь PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая возможность имеется с помощью двух методов:

- [pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)
- [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method)

Пример использования:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "http://xx.x/index?brand[]=1");
```

Ну, в вашем случае привяжите событие к инпуту и по нажатию добавьте строку смены url.

Ссылки на другие ресурсы:

- [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/5275890)
- [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340186/5275890)
- [Управление историей браузера](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Также нашел на ruSO похожие вопросы:

- [Как изменить адресную строку браузера без перезагрузки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/85380/189339)
- [Изменение url в адресной строке браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/136862/189339)